# Como llamar una función desde otro js?

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer lo siguiente:

archivo1.js-----> tengo una función que obtiene un arreglo y ejecuta lo que debe hacer

archivo2.js-----> Este llama al otro archivo y llama la función para mandarle el objeto

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Comparte tu código y en qué plataforma estas trabajando, node o el browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es simple, lo que debemos hacer es importar el archivo JS en el html, los dos a la vez es decir:`

```
<html>
    <?--importamos dos scripts de js -->
    <script src="js/archivo1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/archivo2.js"></script>
</html>
```

Archivo1.js

```
//creamos una funcion que reciba un objeto y que muestre lo que hay dentro de ese objeto
    function mostrar(objeto){
        //creamos una variable para mostrar el objeto
        var texto = "";
        //recorremos el objeto
        for(var i in objeto){
            //mostramos el objeto
            texto += i + ": " + objeto[i] + "<br>";
        }
        //mostramos el objeto
        document.write(texto);
    }
```

Archivo2.js

```
//creamos una funcion que genere un objeto y llame a la funcion mostrar 
    function CrearObjeto(){
        //creamos un objeto
        var objeto = {
            nombre: "Juan",
            apellido: "Perez",
            edad: 30
        };
        //llamamos a la funcion mostrar y le pasamos el objeto
        mostrar(objeto);
```